# How do you take ownership of your comments?

Tags: webapp-rec

Answers so far (and what these services ought to deliver):

- **Disqus Profile** (full ownership on Disqus enabled sites, claiming authorship on others)
- **Intense Debate]** (for blog publishers: tightly integrated into the WordPress blogging platform)
- **BackType Connect Plugin** (for blog publishers: copies comments (that link to one of your posts) to your blog, no matter where they are on the web)
- **Gravatar** (self-promotion, better visibility)
- **Google Sidewiki** (adds another layer)
- become a **blog** publisher

In addition, here are some other services:

- **co.mment** (conversation tracker)
- **coComment** (conversation tracker - still alive and kicking?)
- **Google Reader: "Like"** item action (appreciation feedback)

**Convenient solutions for ordinary netizens** preferred.

---

For your reading pleasure:

> **Comment ownership** is a complex
>   problem. The commenter writes the
>   comment, but the blog owner hosts it.
>   So of course, the blog owner has the
>   right to decide what he agrees to host
>   or not. But the person who wrote the
>   comment might also want to claim some
>   right to his writing once it’s
>   published.
>   ("Who Owns Your Comments?"
>   by Stephanie Booth)

Comment: As essentially you're asking for a list of applications, this question should probably be community wiki.

Comment: How do you intend to take ownership of your comments on your content, if you are not a publisher?

Comment: Comment ownership is a basic necessity for everyone on the web, don't you agree on that?

Comment: What do you mean by "comment ownership".  A brief description should be part of the question.

Comment: @Free in order for users to better answer your questions, please edit your question describing fully what you mean. There seems to be some confusion. Otherwise users will be shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Free Speech Advocate: Even after reading your recommend essay (and the title of your question of course) it is unclear to me what "comment ownership" is. And even if that had been explained on that page it can just vanish any time. I recommend putting an explanation inside the question.

Comment: @neo: You want me to start a philosophical debate on what "ownership" means in the digital realm?

Comment: @Free Speech Advocate: I'm just asking what you expect by "taking ownership of your comments". The right to delete and edit any of your comments anytime? The right to post any comment without the site owner's permission (e.g. critical ones)?

Comment: @neo: Though I have not tried Disqus yet, to me this service seems to be the first one that handles comment ownership in a way that suits both sides (i.e. commenters and hosts).

Comment: Definitely a good thread for me to see. I thought co.mments.com was dead, but apparently it's back and kicking.

Comment: @Free, I added the explanation again to clarify the question. It made it much easier for me to understand the question, so please leave it in.

Comment: @eagle: Your addition ("Is there any way for this to be reversed and give those privileges to the user?") is misleading. Due to restrictions for new users I was not allowed to delete just that; please refrain from putting it in again.

Comment: @free: fair enough, I didn't fully understand what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Disqus](http://disqus.com/profile/) is one of the solutions.

Comment: that was quick and helpful. thx.

Comment: Hm. This service seems to require action on both sites of the equation. What if the site owner (where you want to comment on) has never heard of Disqus? ("Disqus Profile makes it easy and fun to post comments on sites using Disqus Comments.")

Comment: Unfortunately, any service of this kind requires action on both sides.

Comment: Disqus has always been really useful!

Comment: @Alex: Oh yeah? Then this has to change. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Free Speech Advocate: How should this change?

Comment: @neo: Do you try to convince me that there is no appropriate solution around yet?

Comment: @Free Speech Advocate: How? If the site where you post your comment doesn't support your service (be that Disqus or Gravatar or anything else), how do you post it?

Comment: @Alex: What about a web standard for commenting?

Comment: @Free Speech Advocate: Even then the service needs to implement it. Or it needs to be implemented on the browser level (and remember how long it takes to adapt web standards and how many people still use IE6). The Google Sidewiki is the the most-used solution for this side of the implementation.

Comment: @neo: A web standard for handling comment ownership would make implementation less of an issue, don't you agree? Google Sidewiki adds a second layer that is visible for Google Sidewiki users alone, and the host is left out.

Comment: @Free Speech Advocate: I'm not sure what you expect by this web standard. Should the host as well as the commenter be allowed to remove comments? I see the issue that it's still not possible to leave comments if the host does not like it because then he just doesn't implement it. As an addition it is very unlikely that this standard reaches a critical mass.

Answer (score 0):

[Intense Debate](http://intensedebate.com/) would be another choice.

Edit: From what I understand, You need to just take ownership of your comments: Use [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/)

You can also create profiles at Intense Debate and Disqus which would let you take ownership

Comment: Is this service not about publisher's needs?

Comment: Well, yes. The closest I could find relevant to your question was http://www.backtype.com/plugins/connect

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best (in my opinion) current way (excluding a *new* web standard) is to use your own **self-hosted** blog.

Lets take for example this question and I wanted to make a comment so neither the site owner nor moderators can modify or delete my comment.

---

**phwd's** blog

[Start]

*Title*

[How do you take ownership of your comments?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/how-do-you-take-ownership-of-your-comments)

*Body*

> > Intense Debate] (for blog publishers: tightly integrated into
> >     the WordPress blogging platform)
>
> This guy is interested in unicorns.[This is my comment]

Copyright ©2005-2010 Pho Ward

[End]

---

Now notice here this would be my entire page from the blog title, heading, body and copyright information at the end. I have not included a comment section. [I have also added the same comment to WebApps as well to compare]

If Webapps does not have some terms such as "I own your comments" then I *should* have every right to ask for removal of my comment (or no modification). Now lets say a couple months passed and I want to retrieve the comment I made (it holds valuable information to me), but WebApps is out of service or has experienced a database loss. Who is to blame ? Does right of commenting extend to right of existence ?

Now adding in my solution, as long as search engines are crawling my content, my comment is *as* viewable as the post itself and untouchable by the WebApps. Maybe not the same ranking but still visible.

A good example of this implementation is http://daringfireball.net/